# Display a select option on a condition in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, interpolation

I want to display a select option on a condition like this :

```
    <select id="updateType" class="form-control" formControlName="updateType">
        <option value="personalDetails">Personal</option>
        <option value="addressDetails">Address}</option>
        <option *ngIf="{{userModalData.orgTypeCode == 'BO'}}" value="financialDetails">Financial</option> 
                  <!-- Fake Implementation -->
   </select>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `*ngIf`.

```
<select id="updateType" class="form-control" formControlName="updateType">
 <option value="personalDetails">Personal</option>
 <option value="addressDetails">Address</option>
 <option *ngIf="userModalData.orgTypeCode == 'BO'" value="financialDetails">Financial</option> 
</select>
```

Created a quick Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kpygbf

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ngIf` like that

```
 <option *ngIf="userModalData.orgTypeCode == 'BO'" value="financialDetails">Financial</option>
```

Please look https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf for more details